# Hibernate criteria restrict join on multiple tables

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have my existing parent class a with joins to child classes b(one-Many),c(One-one),d(One-one).I am writing a criteria to filter the result based on joining with one of the child class such that it should not fire query joining other tables.Is there a way we can restrict joing with other tables when firing the query?

Note: Cannot use lazy load to pull other relations

Answer (score 0):

Criteria uses all the Persistent objects related to each other. I believe using Detached Criteria is appropriate for your scenario.
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/DetachedCriteria.html